# C# How to lessen a CPU usage to 5% and below in a Network File Transfer?

Tags: c#, cpu-usage

I have a Network File Transfer here. It works fine and great. But I just had a problem on how to lessen my CPU usage to 5% in transferring small files like 200kb and below.

All the large file I transfer just had a 0 - 2% of CPU usage. But when I tried to transfer a small file it bursts to 7%  to 20%. How could that be?

Any suggestions?

Here's my code...

For my Client:

```
private void SendFiles(){
try
        {
            FileInfo file;

            //Checks first if it is connected
            if (tcpClient.Connected == false)
            {
                //Create new instance 
                tcpClient = new TcpClient();

                // Connect the TCP client to the specified IP and port
                tcpClient.Connect(txtIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
            }

            // Get a stream connected to the server
            streamSend = tcpClient.GetStream();

            // byte[] byteSend = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
            byte[] byteSend = new byte[byteLength];

            int listCount = arrList.Count - indxItems;
            byteSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(listCount.ToString().PadRight(byteLength).ToCharArray());

            // Write the sequence of bytes (the count of the items in the listbox) to the network stream
            streamSend.Write(byteSend, 0, byteSend.Length);

            while (indxItems < arrList.Count)
            {
                fName = arrList[indxItems].ToString();

                // grab file info
                file = new System.IO.FileInfo(fName);

                SendFile(fName, streamSend, byteSend);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                minimizeMemory();
                indxItems++;
            }

            if (indxItems == arrList.Count)
                if (MessageBox.Show("Done Sending!\r\nClearing list of sent file(s) and/or folder(s)", "Done Sending", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Clear(this.ClearList), new object[] { true });
                    tcpClient.Close();
                    streamSend.Close();
                    readFile.Close();
                }
        }
        catch (SocketException exMessage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't send, Server not available.\r\nSearch for another connection.", "Sending Error!");
            this.Invoke(new Clear(this.ClearList), new object[] { true });
        }
```

}

For my SendFile Method:

```
private void SendFile(String fName, NetworkStream netStream, byte[] byteSend)
    {
        minimizeMemory();
        try
        {
    readFile = new FileStream(fName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            // Get file info about the opened file
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fName);

            // Get and store the file size
            long FileSize = Convert.ToInt64(fileInfo.Length);

            // Get and store the file name
            String FileName = fileInfo.Name;

            byteSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FileName.PadRight(byteLength).ToCharArray());

            // Write the sequence of bytes (file name) to the network stream
            netStream.Write(byteSend, 0, byteSend.Length);

            byteSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FileSize.ToString().PadRight(byteLength).ToCharArray());

            // Write the sequence of bytes (file size) to the network stream
            netStream.Write(byteSend, 0, byteSend.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(50);

            int byteRead = 0;
            // Define the buffer size
            byte[] downBuffer = new byte[byteLength];

            // Loop through the file strem of the local file
            while (((byteRead = readFile.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0) && (streamSend != null))
            {
                // Write the data that composes the file to the network stream
                netStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteRead);
                uploadSize += byteRead;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            minimizeMemory();
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't connect, Server not available.", "Connection Error!");
            this.Invoke(new Clear(this.ClearList), new object[] { true });
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Action might be closed by the Server.", "Connection Error!");
            this.Invoke(new Clear(this.ClearList), new object[] { true });
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Action might be closed by the Server.", "Connection Error!");
            this.Invoke(new Clear(this.ClearList), new object[] { true });
        }
    }
```

And here's for my Server:

```
private void DownloadFromConnection(TcpClient tcpConn, String ipadd)
    {
        try
        {
            bool disconnected = false;
            fCount = 0;
            success = 0;
            byteLength = 1024 * 100;

            // For holding the number of bytes we are reading at one time from the stream
            int bytesSize = 0;

            // String to hold the FilePath
            String filePath = String.Empty;
            // The buffer that holds the data received from the client
            byte[] downloadBuffer = new byte[byteLength];

            // Receive the stream and store it in a NetworkStream object
            strRemote = tcpConn.GetStream();

            // Read the first buffer(byteLength bytes) from the stream - which represents the count of file(s)/folder(s) to be received.
            bytesSize = strRemote.Read(downloadBuffer, 0, byteLength);

            fCount = Convert.ToInt32(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(downloadBuffer, 0, bytesSize).Trim());

            if (fCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = fCount; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    disconnected = DownloadFilesFromConnection(bytesSize, ipadd, filePath, downloadBuffer);

                    if (disconnected)
                        break;

                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    minimizeMemory();
                }

                if (success == fCount)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(fCount + " file(s) from " + ipadd + " successfully received.", "File Received");
                }
            }
            isReceiving = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            this.Invoke(new UpdateStatusCallback(this.UpdateStatus), new object[] { false, 0 });
        }
        finally
        {
            // This part of the method will fire no matter wether an error occured in the above code or not
            if (strLocal != null && strRemote != null)
            {
                // Close the streams
                strLocal.Close();
                strRemote.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

For DownloadFilesFromConnection Method:

```
private bool DownloadFilesFromConnection(int byteSize, String ipAddress, String filepath, byte[] downloadBuffer)
    {
        minimizeMemory();
        // Cancels receiving operations if client is disconnected
        bool clientDisconnected = false;

        try
        {
            // The buffer that holds the data received from the client
            downloadBuffer = new byte[byteLength];
            this.Invoke(new IsCurrReceivingF(this.IsCurrRecF), new object[] { true });

            // Read the buffer (byteLength bytes) from the stream - which represents the file name
            byteSize = strRemote.Read(downloadBuffer, 0, byteLength);
            // Convert the stream to string and store the file name
            FName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(downloadBuffer, 0, byteSize).Trim();

            // String to hold the FilePath
            filepath = destPath + "\\" + FName;
            this.Invoke(new UpdateStatusCallback(this.UpdateStatus), new object[] { true, 1 });

            // Set the file stream to the path C:\ plus the name of the file that was on the sender's computer
            strLocal = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            // Read the next buffer (byteLength bytes) from the stream - which represents the file size
            byteSize = strRemote.Read(downloadBuffer, 0, byteLength);

            // Convert the file size from bytes to string and then to long (Int64)
            long FileSize = Convert.ToInt64(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(downloadBuffer, 0, byteSize).Trim());
            long size = 0;
            int update = 0;

            // From now on we read everything that's in the stream's buffer because the file content has started
            while ((byteSize = strRemote.Read(downloadBuffer, 0, downloadBuffer.Length)) >= 0 && size != FileSize)
            {
                if (byteSize == 0 && size != FileSize)
                {
                   ForceStopDownload(strLocal, strRemote, ipAddress);
                   this.Invoke(new UpdateStatusCallback(this.UpdateStatus), new object[] { false, 1 });
                   if (File.Exists(filepath))
                   {
                       File.Delete(filepath);
                       this.Invoke(new UpdateStatusCallback(this.UpdateStatus), new object[] { false, 1 });
                       this.Invoke(new UpdateProgressCallback(this.UpdateProgress), new object[] { 0, 0 });
                       this.Invoke(new UpdateProgressFileCallback(this.UpdateProgressFile), new object[] { 0, 0 });
                       FName = String.Empty;
                   }
                   MessageBox.Show("Only " + success + " file(s) successfully copied from " + ipAddress + ".", "File Transferring Canceled");
                   clientDisconnected = true;
                   break;
                }
                else
                {
                        update++;
                        // Write the data to the local file stream
                        strLocal.Write(downloadBuffer, 0, byteSize);
                        size += byteSize;
                        downloadedSize += byteSize;
                        if (update == 2)
                        {
                            // Update the progressbar by passing the file size and how much we downloaded so far to UpdateProgress()
                            this.Invoke(new UpdateProgressCallback(this.UpdateProgress), new object[] { strLocal.Length, FileSize });
                            this.Invoke(new UpdateProgressFileCallback(this.UpdateProgressFile), new object[] { strLocal.Length, FileSize });
                            update = 0;
                        }
                        if (size == FileSize)
                        {
                            // Write the status to the log textbox on the form (txtLog)
                            this.Invoke(new UpdateProgressCallback(this.UpdateProgress), new object[] { 0, 0 });
                            this.Invoke(new UpdateProgressFileCallback(this.UpdateProgressFile), new object[] { 0, 0 });
                            FName = String.Empty;
                            success++;
                            break;
                        }
                 }

                 Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            if (clientDisconnected)
                 return clientDisconnected;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ode)
        {
            ;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            ;
        }

        return clientDisconnected;
    }
```

I know my codes are not that good. I'm new in C# but hoping to have answers to my questions.=)

Comment: Without showing any code? You're on your own. I'm also quite sure that you probably mean: transferring a larger number of small files. A single short file should not normally produce large load. Also, please phrase questions in real-world goals: we cannot help you get <5% CPU usage levels, but we can help you optimize network transfer code **if shown**

Comment: Why would you want strive for 5% CPU usage? Didn't you pay for the other 95%? You should be worried when you reach 100% CPU usage because then you are limited by the CPU.

Comment: Just something unrelated.... `Socket.SendFile()` usually faster then custom code -- it do magics in kernel... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx0a40c2.aspx